# How to trigger the download popup box using Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, http

I am trying to trigger the download pop up box on firefox using an Ajax jquery call.
my jquery code is this:

```
function download_clip(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/controller/download_clip',
        type: "GET",
        complete: function (data_response) {
            status = data_response.responseText; //the response variable from the presentation controller
            console.log(status);
        }
    });
};
```

in my controller:

```
  def download_clip
       send_file "public/output.mp4", :type=>"video/mp4", :filename => "output.mp4", :x_sendfile=>true, :disposition => 'inline'
  end
```

Any ideas how to trigger the download box?

Answer (score 0):

... well, I think firefox does this by itself if you do

```
document.location.href = "/controller/download_clip";
```

with javascript.